# How to join information from an excel table to a road feature in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, excel

I'm working with GQIS 2.2.0 Valmiera. I've made a shapefile of a road that consists in a single line. Now I want to add information that I have in an excel table about several point in the road. How can I join this informations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a unique field between your shapefile and your excel spreadsheet.

This is done using a Join in QGIS, done from the Joins tab from a layers properties, a bit dated guide but functional:

http://maps.cga.harvard.edu/qgis/wkshop/join_csv.php

Although based on the question I think you will need to either split your single line into the segments covered by your spreadsheet.